# Visually displaying keyboard layouts of X.org? / Also: where do X.org keyboard layouts came from?

Tags: xorg, windows, keyboard-layout

I'd like to visually see how some of the keyboard layouts in X.org look like, as an example in Windows I can see them with a program called [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) or even on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QWERTY-based_layouts_for_Latin_script).

Additionally, from where the layouts to X.org came from? some of them (namely: US International) are very different from their Windows counterparts.

Edit: I would like to see all the possibilities with Ctrl, Shift, AltGr, etc., like in Wikipedia's [Keyboard layout](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) page:

(insert image of US International layout, by anybody who has more reputation)

Comment: There are two separate questions here. The first one is answered in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111624/how-to-display-the-current-keyboard-layout .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more inconvenient than neccessary, but it's the best I could find right now:

```
 setxkbmap -print -layout us | xkbcomp -xkm - - | xkbprint - test.ps
```

will put a nice-ish picture of the US layout in test.ps. (`setxkbmap` supports a whole lot of other flags, in particular `-option` and `-variant` may be of interest to you. For details, see `man setxkbmap`. (Sorry, X keyboard configuration is notoriously hairy.)